# Display pop-up in form through separate php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

There's a pop-up div that I need to display. I have a form `form1`, and a class `data_class` which gets the necessary information from the database and display it in the pop-up div.

**Partial code `data_class`:**

```
case "get_data":
    //some variable declaration here
    //some code here
    //some query here

    $exp = explode("|", $row['notes'], 2); 
    $pos = strpos($exp[0], ' ', 10); //limits word count 
    $lim = substr($exp[0],0,$pos); 

$datas=$datas."<div style=' margin-top:5px; width: 100%;'>".$lim."<a class="btn" data-popup-open="popup-1" href=\"#\" onclick=''>test popup</a></div>";}
```

^this gives me an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'popup' (T_STRING).

**Pop-up div CSS in `form1`:**

```
<style>
    .popup {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        display:none;
        position:fixed;
        top:0px;
        left:0px;
        background:rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    }
    .popup-inner {
        max-width:300px;
        width:90%;
        padding:40px;
        position:absolute;
        top:50%;
        left:50%;
        -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
        box-shadow:0px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,1);
        border-radius:3px;
        background:#fff;
    }
    .popup-close {
        width:30px;
        height:30px;
        padding-top:4px;
        display:inline-block;
        position:absolute;
        top:0px;
        right:0px;
        transition:ease 0.25s all;
        -webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%);
        transform:translate(50%, -50%);
        border-radius:1000px;
        background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        font-family:Arial, Sans-Serif;
        font-size:20px;
        text-align:center;
        line-height:100%;
        color:#fff;
    }
    .popup-close:hover {
        -webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
        transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
        background:rgba(0,0,0,1);
        text-decoration:none;
    }
</style>
```

**HTML pop-up div in `form1`:**

```
<a class="btn" data-popup-open="popup-1" href="#">test popup</a>
<div class="popup" data-popup="popup-1">
    <div class="popup-inner">
        <h2>TITLE HERE</h2>
        <p>this is a trial. display complete information here!</p>
        <p><a data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">Close</a></p>
        <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">x</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Pop-up script in `form1`:**

```
$(function() {
    //OPEN POPUP
    $('[data-popup-open]').on('click', function(e)  {
        var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-open');
        $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    //CLOSE POPUP
        $('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
        var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
        $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I can make it work if it's directly in `form1` but how can I do this through `data_class`? I figured I can't use the script in the `data_class` so now I'm at a complete loss as to where to go from here. What's the best way to go about this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: replace your line with this: `$datas=$datas."<div style=' margin-top:5px; width: 100%;'>".$lim."<a class=\"btn\" data-popup-open=\"popup-1\" href=\"#\" onclick=''>test popup</a></div>";`

Comment: @JigarShah that fixed the error problem. Thanks! The popup window isn't appearing though. Would you know why?

Comment: string of `$datas` was broken due to double quotes used, I have just replaced `"` with `\"` (escaping quotation).

Comment: any other error? what happens when you click .. please check console and try to debug your code

Comment: @JigarShah how is this a duplicate? the main problem isn't the parse error? or is it? the popup window still isn't appearing. no other error just that when I click on the button nothing happens

Comment: fixed it. just had to add the script in `data_class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **single qoutes** instead of **double qoutes** in below lines:

```
$datas=$datas."<div style=' margin-top:5px; width: 100%;'>".$lim."<a class="btn" data-popup-open="popup-1" href=\"#\" onclick=''>test popup</a></div>";}
```

**Do like this :**

```
$datas=$datas."<div style=' margin-top:5px; width: 100%;'>".$lim."<a class='btn' data-popup-open='popup-1' href='#' onclick=''>test popup</a></div>";}
```

comment if am i wrong.

Comment: this fixes the parse error yes. But the pop-up still isn't appearing :(

Comment: are aware of boostrap model?..

Comment: it has already been fixed :) just had to add the script in `data_class`. Thanks!